# How to update column in mysql by joining from another tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I had a database, but I rebuilt it for optimization.

Here it is :

**users**

```
(P) user_id
pseudo
```

**images**

```
(P) image_id
path
```

**tags**

```
(P) tag_id
#image_id
#user_id (INT)
tag
```

The older table tags were like :

**old_tags**

```
(P) tag_id
#image_id
author (VARCHAR)
tag
```

My problem is : old_tags is full of datas (around 6000 rows) and tags is empty, I want to convert all data from old_tags to my new tags table format.  But the column are different, author is a `VARCHAR` and user_id an `INT`.  But there is a link between `old_tags` and `users` because the author refers to the pseudo.

I want something like:

```
UPDATE tags
SET user_id = (SELECT user_id FROM users, old_tags WHERE users.pseudo = old_tags.author)
```

I don't know if it's clear, I want everything the same in the new tags table but instead of 'author' I want the corresponding 'user_id'.
I am working with phpmyadmin, so if possible suggest something I can run directly in it.
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do `INSERT` to add new rows to the table:

```
INSERT INTO tags (tag_id, image_id, user_id, tag)
SELECT ot.tag_id, ot.image_id, u.user_id, ot.tag
FROM old_tags ot
JOIN users u ON ot.author = u.pseudo
```

Comment: Worked at first try, i'm newbie to mysql. Very thank you.